# Exporting Local Dependency Folder with Bazel

Tags: build, bazel, monorepo

I am a bit new to Bazel and have a question about exporting a bunch of dependencies from a single folder.

I have a folder full of folders, each of which are Bazel projects. These are all external dependencies that are present locally. I want to export these upwards from the external dependency folder.

I want to be able to refer to these dependencies (e.g. @dependency_one) in other workspaces (e.g. source_code). What kind of setup do I need in the external folder?

```
project
│    
│
└───external
│   │   WORKSPACE (?)
│   │   BUILD (?)
│   │
│   └───dependency_one
│   │   │   WORKSPACE
│   │   │   ...
│   │   │   ...
│   └───dependency_two
│   |   │   WORKSPACE
│   │   │   ...
│   │   │   ...
└───source_code
│   │   WORKSPACE (?)
│   │   ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[local_repository](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#local_repository) is the way to create an [external repository](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html) for those folders. Something like this in the top-level `WORKSPACE`:

```py
local_repository(
  name = "dependency_one",
  path = "external/dependency_one",
)

local_repository(
  name = "dependency_two",
  path = "external/dependency_two",
)
```

If I'm interpreting your layout correctly, you want `project` to be the [workspace directory](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#workspace), and then everything in `source_code` should be part of that, which means not creating a `source_code/WORKSPACE` file. A `source_code/BUILD` file to write your rules in makes sense though.

Make sure to keep in mind the normal [transitive WORKSPACE dependency](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html#transitive-dependencies) restrictions: you have to load all the external repositories required for `dependency_one` and `dependency_two` in the top-level `WORKSPACE`.

Also, I would avoid `external` as a top-level folder name. Bazel uses that path for some special cases related to external repositories. It's being phased out, but that's still in progress. [--experimental_disable_external_package](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--experimental_disable_external_package), [--experimental_sibling_repository_layout](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--experimental_sibling_repository_layout), and [--nolegacy_external_runfiles](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--legacy_external_runfiles) will disable some of that special treatment, but I'm not sure if those would be enough make your layout work, plus they may break various rules you want to use.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a bazel rule inside external to load all the dependencies? Would it be possible to treat external as a bazel project and refer it to it?

i.e. 
local_repository(
external
....
)

load(@external//:deps.bzl, external_deps)
external_deps()

Is this possible, instead of listing each local repository individually in the Workspace file?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Still might run into problems because it's named `external` though. You could also just create `external/deps.bzl` and then `load('//external:deps.bzl', external_deps)` with the file in the main repository if you wanted.